# Get character corresponding to index number based on list-style-type CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html-lists

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_ol_type_all_css

I want to extract the correct character based on the list-style-type and numerical index in CSS

For example, if I want the character for 3 in `list-style-type: lower-greek;` : γ

Example 2, I want the character for 9 in `list-style-type: cjk-ideographic;` :  九

Example 3, I want the characters 1,2,3 in `list-style-type: lower-roman;` :  i,ii,iii

is there a way to do this easily with code?

I believe characters for 3 would have an index of 2, and characters for 9 would have an index of 8... since indexing starts at 0.

How do I return the correct character(s) for the number(s) I want, based on list-style-type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First Answer (CSS but no JS)

I believe you will have to use the [n-th child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), combined with `list-style-type: 'γ. ';` ([mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type))!

### Checkout @ codepen: https://codepen.io/netrules/pen/yLzBMqK

```html
<ul>
  <li>a, b, c, d</li>
  <li>e, f, g, h</li>
  <li>i, j, k, l</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>now i know my abc's!</li>
</ul>
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: lower-greek;
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  list-style-type: 'γ. ';
}
```

I don't know if there is a better workaround though. I will check out again for future comments.

### Second Answer

Upon second reading, I think what you might be referring to, is actually something similar to what's displayed in this [css-tricks post](https://css-tricks.com/ordered-lists-unicode-symbols/). You can look up the pre-defined counter styles [in this website](https://www.w3.org/TR/predefined-counter-styles/) and then write the corresponding javascript to evaluate and map them. Also relevant: unit tests for CSS3 Counter Styles in relation to browser kits [[url](https://w3c.github.io/i18n-tests/results/custom-counter-styles)].

Here's one way to do it: https://codepen.io/netrules/pen/KKXPWEo

```js
const charmap = "900 ϡ, 800 ω, 700 ψ, 600 χ, 500 φ, 400 υ, 300 τ, 200 σ, 100 ρ, 90 ϟ, 80 π, 70 ο, 60 ξ, 50 ν, 40 μ, 30 λ, 20 κ, 10 ι, 9 θ, 8 η, 7 ζ, 6 στ, 5 ε, 4 δ, 3 γ, 2 β, 1 α";
const processedChars = charmap.split(", ");
const mapArray = processedChars.map(x => {
  let vals = x.split(" ");
  return {rem:vals[0], symbol:vals[1]};
})

function evalNumberToListKey(num) {
  let numCalc = num;
  let out = '';
  for(let element of mapArray) {
    const temp = numCalc%element.rem;
    if(temp !== numCalc) {
      numCalc = temp;
      out += element.symbol;
    }
    if(numCalc === 0) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return out;
}

document.write(evalNumberToListKey(951));
```

Comment: Thanks! The second example is a great start to what I need.  So, to be clear, I will need to re-create the charmaps for every chronology type I want?

I can't just use the list-style-type, and easily get the character that would be present for the nth list item in that list-style-type?

Comment: I guess you could always make 'ghost' lists to extract your symbols from, but I guess the efficient workaround is getting the actual counter styles definitions and extracting the symbols you want from them. Alternatively, try to access the metadata from the browser itself, although if there is a way to do it I am not aware of it at time of posting.

Comment: If this works for you, please make sure to select it as best answer @BD